# Printf between two different for loops not working

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, printf

I am trying to debug using printf. I have inserted it between for loops, but I do not receive the output of it. I am certain that the algorithm is continuing after it and arriving to the end, it's like the reader is ignoring it.

Here's the code :

```
for (i = 0; i < lower; ++i) {
    buf3[i] = (buf[i] + buf2[i] )/2;
    printf("\n %d",buf3[i]);
}
printf("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii %d",i);

for (i; i < upper; ++i) {
    if (upper == num2) {
        buf3[i] += buf2[i]/2;
        printf("\n %d",buf3[i]);

    }
    else {
        buf3[i] += buf[i]/2;
        printf("\n %d",buf3[i]);

    }
}


printf("\n %d",upper);
```

The "hiiiii..." message is the one not being seen on the screen. (I tried replacing it by many other messages such as int or anything else, but in vain. I also tried to put another printf right above the first for loop, again it returned nothing).

Please note that upper and lower aren't huge numbers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is value of `lower` ?

Comment: The value of lower is 14962.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does printf not work before infinite loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508630/why-does-printf-not-work-before-infinite-loop)

Comment: Sorry to tell you but i don't have an infinite loop there ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `printf` in question does not print a newline, so the output is buffered until a later `printf` prints a newline.

Add the newline, and you should see the output:

```
printf("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii %d\n",i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding \n after %d.
Also i is not initialised in the second loop

Comment: It doesn't get deleted after exiting for loop so it is 'initialized'. As for the new line, thank you.